# Retrieve Month, Day and Year values from a String using Java

Tags: java, string, date

How to extract Day, Month and Year values from a string [like 18/08/2012]. I tried using SimpleDateFormat, but it returns a Date object and I observed that all the Get methods are deprecated. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Personally I'd use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which makes life considerably simpler. In particular, it means you don't need to worry about the time zone of the `Calendar` vs the time zone of a `SimpleDateFormat` - you can just parse to a `LocalDate`, which is what the data *really* shows you. It also means you don't need to worry about months being 0-based :)

Joda Time makes many date/time operations much more pleasant.

```
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .withLocale(Locale.UK);

        LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate("18/08/2012");

        System.out.println(date.getYear());  // 2012
        System.out.println(date.getMonthOfYear()); // 8
        System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth());   // 18
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz: Well yes, you'd have to use the Joda Time library, putting it on the classpath. These days I'd suggest using java.time instead though, which *is* part of the standard library.

Answer (score 17):

Simply go for `String.split()`,

```
String str[] = "18/08/2012".split("/");
int day = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
..... and so on
```

Answer (score 9):

This should get you going without adding external jars

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
Date parse = sdf.parse("18/08/2012");  
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
c.setTime(parse);  
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.DATE) + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: This printed `2037`.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse(
    "18/08/2012" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
).getDayOfMonth​() // .getYear​() .getMonth()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Avoid the troublesome legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

### `LocalDate`

```
String input = "18/08/2012" ;
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2012-08-18

### Getter methods

Interrogate for the parts.

```
int d = ld.getDayOfMonth​() ;
int m = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int y = ld.getYear() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

Create a java.util.Calendar object out of that date as follows and extract the date parts:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(<date from simple-date-format).
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

etc.,

Comment: Note that this means you've got to make sure the `SimpleDateFormat` and the `Calendar` use the same time zone, as otherwise you'll get the wrong values. Better to stick to types which *only* deal with dates, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I didn't realize the timezone issue until I saw your response referring to JodaTime.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach may be use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object `get(Calendar.MONT)`

Example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateObj).
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

(or)

You may use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) also.

Answer (score 2):

Use This And Pass the date Value

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
Date parse = sdf.parse("18/01/2018");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(parse);
int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
//+1 Is Important Because if the month is January then coming 0 so Add +1
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("Date:"+date +":Month:"+ month + ":Year:"+year);
```

Comment: While using `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` was a reasonable answer when this question was asked 6 years ago, those classes are now long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular was always troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Now a days also more number of project is using Lower Version & maximum people are not using java 1.8. People who are using JDK 8 in project this people can happily use Java.time Package

Comment: There’s certainly room for an answer using the outdated and poorly designed classes too, and thanks for contributing one. I just wanted to make clear that this is what it is. Also if upgrading to Java 8 or later is not an option yet, one may still add [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to one’s project and use java.time through it.

Answer (score 1):

In it the String is stored in an array in form of elements, and with the help of split() function, I have separated it and retrieved it from the array str[] and stored in 3 different variables day, month & year.

import java.util.*;

```
public class date {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String str[] = "18/08/2012".split("/");
        int day = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(str[2]);
        System.out.println(day);
        System.out.println(month);
        System.out.println(year);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Comment: To be more specific I have described complete code , now is this okay buddy?