# Get day, month and year separately using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have a `SimleDateFormat` like this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm");
String date = format.format(Date.parse(payback.creationDate.date));
```

I'm giving date with the format like `"Jan,23,2014"`.

Now, I want to get day, month and year separately. How can I implement this?

Comment: is your current implementation working?

Comment: yeah this two line working fine

Comment: do you want get day, month and year as separate output?

Comment: Your formatting pattern does not match your example input data String.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need to get the values separately, then use more than one `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
String day = dayFormat.format(Date.parse(payback.creationDate.date));

SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
String month = monthFormat .format(Date.parse(payback.creationDate.date));
```

etc.

Comment: Yes bro i wanted to tell this. Works fine for me. Thanks

Comment: Note Date.parse() is @deprecated and as per API it is recommend to use DateFormat.parse

Comment: Yes, Date.parse() is deprecated, so it's better to use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12042621/2914140.

Comment: More than one `SimpleDateFormat` can be avoided by using `applyPattern`.

Comment: What does "payback" do here and where does it come from?

Comment: @waseefakhtar `payback` is a variable from the question author's code, I just copied it into my answer.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 14):

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date theDate = format.parse("JAN 13,2014  09:15");

    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    myCal.setTime(theDate);

    System.out.println("Day: " + myCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    System.out.println("Month: " + myCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    System.out.println("Year: " + myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 8):

Wow, `SimpleDateFormat` for getting string parts? It can be solved much easier if your input string is like "Jan,23,2014":

```
String input = "Jan,23,2014";
String[] out = input.split(",");
System.out.println("Year = " + out[2]);
System.out.println("Month = " + out[0]);
System.out.println("Day = " + out[1]);
```

Output:

```
Year = 2014
Month = Jan
Day = 23
```

But if you really want to use `SimpleDateFormat` because of some reason, the solution will be the following:

```
String input = "Jan,23,2014";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(input);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Output:

```
2014
23
Jan
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer here suggests to use more than one `SimpleDateFormat`, but it's possible to do this using one `SimpleDateFormat` instance and calling `applyPattern`.

**Note: I believe this post would also be helpful for those who were searching for setPattern() just like me.**

```
Date date=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("dd");
System.out.println("Day   : " + simpleDateFormat.format(date));
simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("MMM");
System.out.println("Month : " + simpleDateFormat.format(date));
simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy");
System.out.println("Year  : " + simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "Jan,23,2014" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM,dd,uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
.getYear()
```

… or `.getMonthValue()` or `.getDayOfMonth`.

## java.time

The other Answers use outmoded classes. The java.time classes supplant those troublesome old legacy classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "Jan,23,2014";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM,d,uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Interrogate for the parts you want.

```
int year = ld.getYear();
int month = ld.getMonthValue();
int dayOfMonth = ld.getDayOfMonth();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use this to parse "Jan,23,2014"

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM','dd','yyyy"); 
Date dt = fmt.parse("Jan,23,2014");
```

then you can get whatever part of the date.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accepting this ?

```
int day = 25 ; //25
int month =12; //12
int year = 1988; // 1988
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month-1, day, 0, 0);    
SimpleDateFormat format =   new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm");
System.out.println(format.format(c.getTime()));
```

Display as `Dec 25,1988  12:00`

UPDATE : based on Comment

```
DateFormat format =   new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
System.out.println(format.format(format.parse("Jan,23,2014")));
```

NOTE: Date.parse() is @deprecated and as per API it is recommend to use DateFormat.parse

Comment: i want to get only day or mounth in dateformat in my code. Not completed date.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat) {
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified
        // format.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,
                Locale.getDefault());

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in
        // milliseconds to date.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: -1 This doesn't address the question. It's just a pile of date-formatting-related code.