# Get year, month and day from parsed date

Tags: scala

I have the following code to validate a date given a date format:

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
df.setLenient(false);

try {
   val date = df.parse("11/13/2014");
}
catch {
  case pe: ParseException => println("date error")
}
```

Now, what I need is to obtain the year, month and day in three variables. What is the best way to achieve this? Note that I need a solution based on performance as I need to validate/convert thousands of dates.

Comment: Simple... go read the documentation for Date API. Try it out then ask here if you still have problems.

Comment: it says that getYear is deprecated, that's why I asked

Comment: I'd use joda-time or java.time in any case.

Comment: Create an instance of calendar. Use `setTime` method of calendar to set it to your date. Now you have the calendar instacne for your date. Now use the hint given in the deprecation message and you will get your year etc.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @laughedelic because that will require me to write the actual code. Which may lead to a copy paste behaviour without any effort to understand.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I think you don't *have to* write the code, but providing an explanation with a link to docs would be useful for other people too. On the other hand if you think that the question doesn't deserve an answer, flag it (with a reason, of course).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get day, month and year separately using SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22989840/get-day-month-and-year-separately-using-simpledateformat)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## java.time

Use Java 8 and the new date/time API. Better, cleaner, future-proof.

```
val dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
val dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)
val dateString = "11/13/2014"
val d = java.time.LocalDate.parse(dateString, dtf)
val year = d.getYear
```

> 2014

```
val monthNumber = d.getMonthValue
```

> 11

You can access a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object.

```
val month = d.getMonth
```

> Month.NOVEMBER

```
val dayOfMonth = d.getDayOfMonth
```

> 13

Once you have the input parsed into a [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), you can get the year with getYear, etc.

To validate, catch the [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) generated for invalid inputs.

If you want to skip the proper date validation (e.g. for performance) and just extract the Y, M, D - you can split the string and get integers as shown below

```
val ymd = dateString.split("/").map(_.toInt)
ymd: Array[Int] = Array(11, 13, 2014)
```

Comment: What is the point of *parsing* a `LocalDate` if then you just split the string? Use `LocalDate` methods instead: [`d.getYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getYear--), [`d.getMonthValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonthValue--), etc.

Comment: OP mentioned "validation". Parsing it as a date is the ultimate validation that it's a date, not just slash-separated integers (e.g. "65/82/1314"). OP is free to use as little / much of the solution as needed

Comment: He says: "Now, what I need is to obtain the year, month and day in three variables".